# How to make variable rectangle sizes in latex organigram chart

Tags: tikz-trees

I hope adapted the following organigram chart from [How to convert my word organisation chart to latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246831/how-to-convert-my-word-organisation-chart-to-latex?rq=1) as replied by @alien (thanks very much @alien). The code works very fine. However, the rectangles at levels 3 and 4 (run, test and em_real) are bigger than those at levels 1 and 2. Secondly, the text at these levels (3 and 4) is not centered. Is it possible to reduce the rectangle sizes at these levels, and center the text?
Assistance will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
        align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},
      },
      draw,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      l sep=10mm,
      tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
      edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
      ultra thick,
      inner color=blue,
      outer color=gray!20,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      drop shadow,
      s sep=0.5cm,
      minimum width=2cm,
      minimum height=1cm,
    }
    [DA
      [WPS]
      [WRF
        [\color{green}run]
        [\color{orange}test
          [\color{green}em\_real]
        ]
      ]
      [3DVAR]
      [4DVAR]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could delete `if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
        align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},` from your code

Comment: Thanks for that @hpekristiansen, the code works with that deletion. The text is aligned correctly for levels 1 and 2 but aligned center bottom for 3 and 4. The rectangle sizes remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest, array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
draw,
font=\sffamily\bfseries,
edge path={
\noexpand\path[draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
l sep=10mm,
tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
ultra thick,
inner color=blue,
outer color=gray!20,
rounded corners=2pt,
drop shadow,
s sep=0.5cm,
minimum width=1.8cm,
minimum height=0.6cm,
}
[DA
[WPS]
[WRF
[\color{green}run]
[\color{orange}test
[\color{green}em\_real]
]
]
[3DVAR]
[4DVAR]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tree stucture]

Comment: Thank you very much @hpekristiansen. This does what I was looking for. I really appreciate your time and effort.